# Replace a String from Array to Line in File

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

My file has:

```
 public class MyC{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        System.out.println("My method has been accessed");
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

The code below does the following.
 1. If line count equals `num[index]`,it checks whether if that line contains the string from 
 `VALUES1[index]`. If true, it replace that string from the first index in `VALUES[index]` and writes to a new file.

2.If num index not equal `num[index]`,it simply writes the line to new file as it is.

**The problem am getting is that after writing to new file, original line 1 and 2 still appears in the new file. How to remove that.**

Heres my code:

```
public class MainTest {


    static int i ;

    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        try {



             int num[] = {1,2,4}; //Line Numbers

             String[] VALUES = new String[] {"AB","BC","CD"}; //Correct Solutions

             String[] VALUES1 = new String[] {"class","void","System"}; //To Replace


             FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File.txt");
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

             FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Antish\\Desktop\\Test_File1.txt");

             String line;
             String line1 = null;

             Integer count =0;

             line = br.readLine();
             count++;

             while(line!=null){


                 for(int index =0;index<num.length;index++){
                     if(count == num[index]){

                         if(line.contains(VALUES1[index])){

                             line1= line.replace(VALUES1[index], VALUES[index]);
                              writer1.write(line1+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                         }


                     }
                 }


                 writer1.write(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

                 line = br.readLine();

                 count++;


                 }


        writer1.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }

     }
}
```

Here is my result:

```
    public AB MyC{
    **public class MyC{ //This still appears.**
    public BC MyMethod()
    **public void MyMethod()//This still appears.**
    {
        CD.out.println("My method has been accessed");
        System.out.println("My method has been accessed");
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is already not first your question about mistakes in concretely this project. May be it would be better if you fully review the approach, which you chosen for implementing your idea?

Comment: Am implementing the project in pieces. the issues am facing and cant find solutions am referring to the site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add an indicator to show if this line is replaced

while(line!=null){

```
             boolean exists = false;
             for(int index =0;index<num.length;index++){
                 if(count == num[index]){

                     if(line.contains(VALUES1[index])){
                         exists = true;
                         line1= line.replace(VALUES1[index], VALUES[index]);
                          writer1.write(line1+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     }


                 }
             }

             if (!exists)
                 writer1.write(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

comment this line in code

```
writer1.write(line+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

then try

Comment: Thanks only line to be replaced are written. The above answer by Kai worked perfectly.